# Error while creating a decision tree

Tags: sas, decision-tree

I want to create with sas procedure **hpsplit** a tree decision on this data :

```
 | city       | studied_area     | salary |
 ------------------------------------------
1| manchester | biology          | 40000  |
2|  london    | computer science | 50000  |
3| reading    | computer science | 45000  |
```

Each line represent a person. The variables are the city where he get his degree, the studied area and his actual salary.

I want to create a decision tree using the first two variables to guess the salary variable.

I started by doing this :

```
proc hpsplit data=lib1.wagesdata seed=15531;
class salary city studied_area;
model salary = city studied_area;
grow entropy;
prune costcomplexity;
run;
```

I used this doc : https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/141/hpsplit.pdf

But I have the following errors :

```
ERROR: Character variable appeared on the MODEL statement without appearing on a CLASS statement.
ERROR: Unable to create a usable predictor variable set.
```

Can you explain me why and how can I fix this ?

UPDATED : Simply added all the variables in the class clause to avoid the errors which is weird because in the doc that's not the case for the first example.
I added a format for my salary because the output wasn't understandable.

Comment: Why does your data listing show only three variables when your CLASS and model statement reference four variables?  Did you mean to have one variable named STUDIED_AREA instead of two different variables named STUDIED and AREA?

Comment: fixed, i need to wear my glasses ...

Comment: Don't you get an error with that GROW syntax? Also why are you treating SALARY as a class variable?  Isn't it a number?